# Intuition of Mercer's theorem?

Tags: functional-analysis

I have recently been trying to gain some intuition about [Mercer's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem):

$$K(x,y)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda_ie_i(x)e_i(y)$$

According to [this video](https://youtu.be/juTjfwTZ7XQ?t=475), each symmetric, positive semi-definite kernel constitutes an inner product in some associated (Reproducing Kernel) Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. This is relatively clear to me, as the equation above can be easily interpreted as an inner product between

$$k(\cdot,x)=[\sqrt{\lambda_1}e_1(x),...,\sqrt{\lambda_\infty}e_\infty(x)]$$
$$k(\cdot,y)=[\sqrt{\lambda_1}e_1(y),...,\sqrt{\lambda_\infty}e_\infty(y)]$$

What has me stumped, however, is on what basis exactly this associated Hilbert space is formed. Since we have eigenfunctions $e_i$ and eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, we must have decomposited some linear operator. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem), this operator was the [Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator) defined on some functions $\phi$.

$$[T_K\phi](x)=\int_a^bK(x,s)\phi(s)ds$$

But why exactly this integral operator and not something else? From where to where are these functions $\phi$ mapping? Are they functions defined in the Hilbert space? Why are they absent from both Mercer's theorem and the RKHS? The derivation just seems rather arbitrary to me. Is there something I have misunderstood?